# Selecting the last 5 rows in a table except the last row

Tags: mysql

I wanted to select the last 5 entries of the table except the last entry of the table. I have a table which maintains the details of the weeks of the year. So in order to get the report of the last 5 weeks I have to extract the data from the table. I do not want the data of this week. So how to select the data of last five weeks except this week's data.

Comment: Please provide your attempt with proper table definitions and some sample data set related to your question

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply Sir. I got the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let id be the primary key of your table which is auto-increment. then you can use the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: it is great if you vote and mark it as a answer...thanks

Comment: Sir now I wanted to refer another table from the result of this data. 'select (day1+day2), id from  project_timesheet where week_ref=(
SELECT id FROM (
    SELECT id FROM weeks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5);' But it is showing that the sub query returns more than one row.

Comment: use this query...'select (day1+day2), id from project_timesheet where week_ref in ( SELECT id FROM ( SELECT id FROM weeks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6 ) sub ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5);'

Comment: Its showing that 'Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery''

Comment: try this..'select (pt.day1+pt.day2), pt.id from project_timesheet pt join ( SELECT id FROM 
( SELECT id FROM weeks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6 ) sub ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5)temp on pt.week_ref=temp.id;'

Answer (score 0):

If you have same date information in the table you can select the data in a time range:

```
select * from table where date >= [startdate] and date <= [enddate]
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be much simpler:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1,5;
```

Comment: In case of your code, the result will be in descending order. If we want the result set in ascending order. Then the above code works fine.